# How to get response header value in angular ngrx effect

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a ngrx effect that makes api GET call and need to get a **response header** value ( like pagination added to the header). Currently my response result only has the typed object. How I can get the response header in ngrx effect and add to the payload

Effect:

```
filterCandidates$ = createEffect(() => 
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(candidateActions.filterCandidate),
          switchMap((payload) => 
            this.candidateApiService.filterCandidate(payload.candidateFilters, payload.options).pipe(
              tap(ev => console.log(ev)),
              map((result) => candidateActions.filterCandidateSuccess({ result })),  
              catchError((error: Error) => of(candidateActions.filterCandidateFailed({ error })))
            )
          )
        )
);
```

Api Service:

```
  filterCandidate(candidateFilter: candidateFilter): Observable<Result<Candidate>> {

    if (candidateFilter) {
      if (candidateFilter.keyword) {
        params = params.append('keyword', candidateFilter.keyword);
      }

    }
   
    params = params.append('pageNumber', candidateFilter.pageNumber.toString())
      .append('pageSize', candidateFilter.pageSize.toString())
      .append('sortBy', candidateFilter.sortBy)
      .append('sortByDirection', candidateFilter.sortDirection);

    return this.httpClient.get<Result<Candidate>>(`${this.appConfig.apiUrl}/candidate/filter`, { params });
  }
```

Comment: I am little bit confused by your question: You ask for receiving http headers '( like pagination ...)', but pagination is usualy done by urlQueryParameters such as `?page=1&size=10`. However, if you really want to access the HTTP Response Headers, then you can access them by adding `{observe: 'response'}` to your params HttpResponse: `.append('observe','response');` and expect the return value to be a HttpResponse: `.get<HttpResponse<Result<Candidate>>>( ...`

Comment: I forgot to mention, that your filterCandidate(..) method then will return an object like `{"body": -your<Result<Candidate>>Object-, "headers": -the original http response headers -, ...}`, but since you are using effects and ngrx, you won't be a beginner and know what to adjust there ;)

Comment: Please see https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/paging-in-aspnet-webapi-http-headers/ .

Comment: Woaw, Ive just learned something => headers also include the Pagination params. Thanks! I probably won't ever make advantage of that, but also won't forget ;-) Have you tried the `{observe: 'response'}` param? let me know if it helped

Comment: The REST API accepts a typed object for the filter and it is returning a typed object as result. So .append('observe','response') is not helping.

Comment: woopsi. The params object was not the location to add it. As timdeschryver answered, the request should be called as `this.httpClient.get<HttpResponse<Result<Candidate>>>(URL, {params, observe: 'response'})`

Answer (score 0):

Use `{ observe: 'response' }` in the http client to retrieve the full response, including body and response headers.

For an example, see the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get HttpHeaders from your service, you have to add `{oberse: 'response'}` to your `httpClient.get()` method. The response then changes from `Observable<Result<Candidate>>`to `Observable<HttpResponse<Result<Candidate>>>`:

```
filterCandidate(candidateFilter: candidateFilter): Observable<HttpResponse<Result<Candidate>>> {
   if (candidateFilter) {
        if (candidateFilter.keyword) {
              params = params.append('keyword', candidateFilter.keyword);
        }
   }
   params = params.append('pageNumber', candidateFilter.pageNumber.toString())
        .append('pageSize', candidateFilter.pageSize.toString())
        .append('sortBy', candidateFilter.sortBy)
        .append('sortByDirection', candidateFilter.sortDirection);
   return this.httpClient.get<HttpResponse<Result<Candidate>>>(`${this.appConfig.apiUrl}/candidate/filter`, { params, observe: 'response' });
}
```

The response type will then be:

```
{
    body: <Result<Candidate>>,
    headers: HttpHeaders
}
```

So you have to adjust your effect according to the new returnType `HttpResponse`:

```
filterCandidates$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(candidateActions.filterCandidate),
      switchMap((payload) => 
        this.candidateApiService.filterCandidate(payload.candidateFilters, payload.options).pipe(
          tap(ev => console.log(ev)),
          map((result) => candidateActions.filterCandidateSuccess({ result })),  // your result now is a JSON including the properties 'body' and 'headers'
          catchError((error: Error) => of(candidateActions.filterCandidateFailed({ error }))) // also here, the 'error' has changes to '{error: any, headers: HttpHeaders}'
        )
      )
    )
);
```

and then you could change your `filterCandidateSuccess(responseBody: Candidate)` method from something like

```
private filterCandidateSuccess(responseBody: Candidate) {
    // some process on responseBody
}
```

to

```
private filterCandidateSuccess(response: HttpResponse) {
    let pageSize: number = undefined;
    let pageNumber: number = undefined;
    if (response.headers.has('pageSize')) {
         pageSize = response.headers.get('pageSize');
    }
    if (response.headers.has('pageNumber')) {
         pageNumber= response.headers.get('pageNumber');
    }
    // continue with your process of the actual responseBody with 'response.body'
}
```

and adjust the same for `filterCandidateFailed()`.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I was able to make it work with adding { params, observe: 'response' }